# How can I split a signal and merge it in again later?

Tags: reactive-cocoa, frp

I'm not quite sure how to do this correctly, and I'm probably missing some notions of FRP since I've not long been playing with ReactiveCocoa.

My situation is this - I have signals which:

- loads an object from a local store;
- loads an object from a remote store;
- saves a remote object to a local store;
- transforms (maps) an object from a local store into a different format

I want to have one signal to which I can subscribe, which will:

- load an object by localId from a local store;
- split signals here, to:

  - send an initial object to the signal's subscriber:

    - transform the object into a different format;
    - send this format to the end subscriber;
  - update the local object from a remote store and send the updated version;

    - load an object from a remote store using a remoteId from the local object just loaded;
    - save that remote object to the local store;
    - reload the object from the local store from the original localId;
    - transform the object into a different format;
    - send this format to the end subscriber;
    - complete the signal.

The idea behind all this is that my main load object signal should return an initial version of the object (as stored locally) while updating that object from a remote store and finally sending the updated version. So the end subscriber should receive the object twice before completing.

The remote load signal depends on the local load signal because we have to load out the local object in order to obtain the remoteId for the object. Therefore, I would like to avoid loading out the local object twice (once for sending to the original subscriber and once for obtaining the remoteId in order to load the remote object) when starting the signal.

The initial solution I came up with was to make the local load signal a multicasted (`autoconnected`) signal, then merge this signal (with the transformation chained to it) with the same signal (with the remote load, save, load and transformation chained to it). However, this never proceeds to the remote load, which I can only think is due to the local load signal sending `completed`.

Is there some way to do what I want to do? Have I got the logic all wrong?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a Subject. If you're unfamiliar, a Subject can be subscribed to, just like a normal Signal, but you can explicitly tell it to send values (or errors, or completed messages). You can also subscribe a Subject to a Signal, and the Subject will propagate that Signal's messages to its own subscribers.

You'll probably want to encapsulate this in a prettier way, but I think something like the following will do what you want:

```
let subject = RACSubject()

subject.map {
    let localObject = $0 as! LocalObjectType
    return transformLocalFormToFinalForm(localObject)
}
.subscribeNext { 
    let finalObject = $0 as! FinalObjectType
    // Process your final object here
}


let localObjectId = ... // Assuming the ID exists

getLocalObject(localObjectId).doNext { 
    subject.sendNext($0) 
}
.flattenMap {
    let localObject = $0 as! LocalObjectType
    return getRemoteObject(localObject.remoteId)
}
.flattenMap {
    let remoteObject = $0 as! RemoteObjectType
    return saveRemoteObjectToLocalStore(remoteObject)
}
.flattenMap {
    return getLocalObject(localObjectId)
}
.subscribeNext({
    subject.sendNext($0)
    subject.sendCompleted()
}, error {
    subject.sendError($0)
})
```

This setup should do the following:

1. Get a local object from an ID
2. Send the local object to the subject (this gets transformed and sent to the final subscriber)
3. Use the remote ID from the local object to get the remote object
4. Save the remote object to the local store
5. Get the (now updated) local object from the original ID
6. Send the local object and a completed message to the subject (or an error, if an error occurs anywhere in the chain)

Hope this helps!